# How to do type checking for a recursive function with no explicit return type?

Tags: function, recursion, compiler-construction, typechecking, function-call

I am writing a language where functions are not typed. Which means I need to infer the return type of a function call in order to do type checking. However when somebody writes a recursive function the type checker goes into an infinite recursion trying to infer the type of the function call inside the function body.

The type checker does something like this:

1. Infer the types of the function call actual arguments.
2. Create a mapping of the actual argument types to the formal arguments.
3. Use the mapping to annotate types on the arguments used inside the function body.
4. Infer and return the return type of the function body.

Step 4 tries to then infer the type of the function call inside the function body, which calls the same type checker function again, causing an infinite recursion.

An example of a recursive function that gives me this problem:

```
function factorial(n) = n<1 ? 1 : n*factorial(n-1); // Function definition.
...
assert 24 == factorial(4); // Function call expression usage example.
```

How can I solve this problem without going in to an infinite recursion loop? Is there a way to infer the type of the recursive function call without having to go into the body again? Or some clean way to infer the type from context?

I know the easy solution might be to add types annotations to functions, this way the problem is trivial, but before doing that I want to know if there is a way to solve this without resorting to that.

I'd also like for the solution to work for mutual recursion.

Comment: You have to assign some placeholder type for the function, and then fill it in when more information becomes available. Let's call the type of `factorial` `T`, and proceed. We know that `T` is a function.  Next we see that the function takes an argument, so we update `T` to be "function of one argument". Then see that in the `n < 1` case, it returns `1`. So `T` must be "function of one argument returning integer". Now when we look at `n*factorial(n-1)`, we now know that `n` is being multiplied by an integer, and so on.

Comment: Note that while [so] tends to accept borderline questions about applied computer science like this one, they're more centrally on-topic on [cs.se] and have a better chance of getting good answers there. Do not repost, but if you prefer your question to be on [cs.se], you can flag your question and ask a moderator to migrate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type inference can vary a lot depending on the language's type system and on what properties you want to have in terms of when annotations are needed. But whatever your language looks like, I think there's one seminal case you really should read about, which is [ML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ML_(programming_language)). ML's type inference holds a nice sweet spot where it all fits together in a relatively simple paradigm. No type annotations are needed, and any expression has a single most general type (this property is called *principality* of typing).

ML's type system is the [Hindley-Milner type system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner_type_system), which has [parametric polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_polymorphism). The type of an expression is either a specific type, or “any”. More precisely, the type *constructor* of an expression is either a specific type constructor or “any”, and type constructors can have arguments which themselves either have a specific type constructor or “any”. For example, the empty list has the type “list of any”. Two expressions that can have “any” type in isolation may be constrained to have the same type, whatever it is, so “any” is expressed with variables. For example, `function list_of_two(x, y) = [x, y]` (in a notation like your language) constrains `x` and `y` to have the same type, because they're inserted in the same list, but that type can be any type, so the type of this function is “take any two parameters of the same type α, and return a value of type list of α”.

The basic type inference algorithm for Hindley-Milner is [algorithm W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner_type_system#Algorithm_W). At its core, it works by giving each subexpression a type that's a variable: α₁, α₂, α₃, … Programming language constructions then impose constraints on those variables. For example, if a list contains two elements of types α₁ and α₂ and the list itself has the type α₃, this constraints α₁ = α₂ and α₃ = list of α₁. Putting all these constraints together is a [unification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science)#Syntactic_unification_of_first-order_terms) problem.

The constraints are based on a purely syntactic reading of the program. If there's a recursive call, you don't need to know the type of the function: it just means that there's a constraint that the variable for the return type of the function is the same as the type at its point of use. That's just one more equation to add to the set of constraints.

I left out an important aspect of ML which is that an expression's type can be *generalized*: an expression can be used with different types at different places. This is what allows polymorphism. For example,

```
let empty_list = [] in
(empty_list @ [3]), (empty_list @ ["hello"])
```

is a valid program where `empty_list` is used once with the type “list of integers” and once with the type “list of strings”. The type of `empty_list` is “for any α, list of α”: that's parametric polymorphism. Generalization adds some complexity to the algorithm, but it also removes complexity elsewhere, because that's what allows principality. Without it, `let empty_list = [] in …` would be ambiguous: `empty_list` would have to have some type, but there's no way to know what type without analyzing `…`, and then when you do analyze the `…` above you'd need to make a choice between integer and string.

Depending on your language's type system, ML and algorithm W may be directly reusable or may just provide some vague inspiration. But the principle of using variables during the inference, and progressively constraining these variables, is very general.

Comment: [This](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2018/type-inference/) post explains the Hindley-Milner type system very clearly and it even includes an example. It complements this answer very well. Great starting point for anyone who wants to implement the system for their own language.